# Determine the differential equation of the orthogonal trajectories of the ellipse family $x ^ 2 + 3y ^ 2 = ay$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the differential equation of the orthogonal trajectories of the ellipse family $x ^ 2 + 3y ^ 2 = ay$. Then determine the orthogonal trajectory containing the track $(1,2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2+3y^2=ay$$
$$ 2x+6y \frac {dy}{dx}=a\frac {dy}{dx}$$

$$\frac {dy}{dx} =\frac {2x}{a-6y}=$$

$$\frac {2x}{(\frac {x^2+3y^2}{y})-6y}=$$

$$\frac {2xy}{x^2-3y^2}$$

Thus the orthogonal trajectories are governed by $$ \frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {x^2-3y^2}{2xy}$$

Comment: You must eliminate $a$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for your comment. I fixed my error.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Differentiate

$$a=\frac{x^2}y+3y$$ to eliminate $a$.

Then replace $y'$ by $-\dfrac1{y'}$ and integrate.

Comment: can you complete the whole task?

Comment: @DjordjeZivadinovic: sorry, no, your job. The instructions are straightforward.

Comment: Is it a homogeneous equation?

Comment: @DjordjeZivadinovic: which one ?

Comment: This x^2+3y^2=ay

Comment: @DjordjeZivadinovic: no, it's not. The degrees differ.